# Chartjs pie chart tooltip mode label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chartjs we can write for bar charts for example

```
options: {
 tooltips: {
  mode: 'label'
 }
}
```

This will display all of the data in the group of data you hover over (based on the x-axis).
How can the same be achieved for a pie chart without use of multistring?

Comment: Please share jsfiddle for your issue else more provide more information to rid out of your problem in short time.

Answer (score 0):

use following for Pie chart:

```
var data = {
labels: [
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow"
]}
```

Comment: All my labels are dynamic from database, so a static approach will not work

Comment: so you can put one for loop and add all labels into one string array and just add that array and then apply that array into labels: arrayLabels

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = [{
     value: 300,
     color: "#F7464A",
     highlight: "#FF5A5E",
     label: "Red"
 }, {
     value: 50,
     color: "#46BFBD",
     highlight: "#5AD3D1",
     label: "Green"
 }, {
     value: 100,
     color: "#FDB45C",
     highlight: "#FFC870",
     label: "Yellow"
 }];
```

Here label act as tooltip